# Functional equation $(n-1)^2 < f(n) f(f(n)) < n^2 +n$.

Tags: functional-equations, functional-inequalities

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$(n-1)^2 < f(n) f(f(n)) < n^2 +n$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is there anything you tried to solve this before posting here? For example, do you know $f(1)$, $f(2)$ and $f(3)$?

Comment: Please try to avoid posting simple equations as images or image links. You can write equations using MathJax markup, eg, your equation can be written as $(n-1)^2 < f(n) \cdot f(f(n)) < n^2 + n$

Comment: Even if you _don't_ know the MathJax syntax, there's no character in your equation that you can't simply type on your keyboard. There really is no excuse for hiding them behind an image.

Comment: @HenningMakholm looks better now, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

We show by induction that any function $f\colon \mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ satisfying
$$
(n-1)^2< f(n)\cdot f(f(n)) < n^2+n\quad \text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$} \tag{1}
$$
is necessarily the identity function.

Let $f$ be a function satisfying (1). For $n=1$ we have
$$
0 < f(1)\cdot f(f(1)) < 2,
$$
i. e. $f(1)\cdot f(f(1)) = 1$, i. e. $f(1)=1$.

Now, assume $f(k)=k$ for $k<n$. We have to show that $f(n)=n$.

- Assume for a contradiction, that $m:= f(n)\le n-1$. Then
  $$
  f(n)\cdot f(f(n)) = m\cdot f(m) = m^2 \le (n-1)^2
  $$
  contradicting $(n-1)^2 < f(n)\cdot f(f(n))$. Hence $f(n)\ge n$.
- Assume for a contradiction, that $m:= f(n) > n$. Then
  $$
  m\cdot f(m) = f(n)\cdot f(f(n)) < n^2+n = n(n+1).
  $$
  Now, $m>n$ implies $f(m)< n+1$, i. e. $f(m) \le n$.

  - If $f(m)<n$, then $f(m)\le m-1$ and by induction hypothesis for $f(m)$
    $$
    f(m)\cdot f(f(m)) = f(m)^2 \le (m-1)^2
    $$
    contradicting (1) for $m$.
  - If $f(m) = n$, then by (1) for $n$
    $$
    mn = f(n)\cdot f(f(n)) < (n+1)n,
    $$
    and hence $m<n+1$, contradicting $m>n$.

Hence also the case $f(n)>n$ leads to a contradiction. It follows that $f(n)=n$.